# Disclose billing cycle information on order page to customers

Tags: commerce

When customer clicks on a recurring order page he can see:

> Billing information:
>   Name Lastname 
>   Some Address
>   Some City, State 11111 United States

and then immediately after that:

> Billing cycle: 
>   - Restricted access -

I looked high and low, tried all the different permissions for products, orders, licenses, but can't figure out how to get billing cycle information displayed on order page. I don't know why billing cycle should be restricted for the customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a module error i can display the cycle type after adding access callback on $entity_info['cl_billing_cycle'] (commerce_license_billing_entity_info function) on commerce_license_billing.module.

Here is the patch file:

```
--- commerce_license_billing.module.bak 2016-03-31 00:02:29.017204562 +0100
+++ commerce_license_billing.module 2016-03-31 00:04:25.376291062 +0100
@@ -85,6 +85,7 @@
     'label' => t('Commerce License Billing Cycle'),
     'module' => 'commerce_license_billing',
     'base table' => 'cl_billing_cycle',
+    'access callback' => 'commerce_license_billing_cycle_type_access',
     'entity class' => 'CommerceLicenseBillingCycle',
     'controller class' => 'EntityAPIController',
     'metadata controller class' => 'CommerceLicenseBillingCycleMetadataController',
```

Comment: It was working before, but now it is not. It shows just empty field. Related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207201/views-field-for-billing-cycle-always-returns-empty?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your roles/permissions that users have permissions to view licenses:

[image]

Comment: Been there, tried, but unfortunately it will still remain - Restricted access - for the customers even if you give them "Administer licenses" permission.

Comment: This is crazy, but I never checked that filed as user #1 and now I did and see the same `Billing cycle: - Restricted access -`. So it is not available even to admin.