# Views field for Billing cycle always returns empty

Tags: commerce

I've added the following field to Views

```
Commerce Order: Billing cycle (Billing cycle)
```

and unfortunately it always returns empty whereas other fields as Created,  Updated,    Status return their values normally.

In fact it is not Views field issue, because if I click on any order item and go to its page the Billing cycle is empty there too. I applied the patch on [Disclose billing cycle information on order page to customers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186373) and I hope it didn't cause this issue.

Comment: According to patch, it applies access callback on it. Have you checked what commerce_license_billing_cycle_type_access this function does?

Comment: But I am checking as user #1, so should override any access permissions.

Comment: But sometimes in the function we forgot to give permissions to user #1. So, just check whether that function is allowing us the permission or not.

Comment: Well, I just did and user #1 has all the permissions, because with I have https://www.drupal.org/project/adminrole